# Display image from MySql database in Php server

Tags: php, android, mysql

I send an image from my Android Application to my Php server using a MySql database, but when i try to display the image in browser it doesn't work.
This is how I send the picture

```
 String imageString=Base64.encodeBytes(this.image);
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", imageString));
```

And this is how I try to display it

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"/>';
```

I've checked and imageString in my app is different from `base64_encode( $row['image'])`.

MySql part

```
$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE Posts (
id INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
user VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
date VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
event VARCHAR(1000),
image BLOB
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table Posts created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);
$user = $_POST['user'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$event = $_POST['event'];
$image = $_POST['image'];

echo "Test";
$sql = "INSERT INTO Posts (user, date, event,image) ";
$sql .= "VALUES ('$user','$date', '$event', '$image')";
if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
 echo "Insert success";
}
mysql_close($con);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["user"]. $row["date"].  $row["event"].  "<br>";


      echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"/>';
```

Comment: Where is the MySql in your code?

Comment: 'mysql_close($con);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {'. ??? You close the connection and then use $result? The $result of what? Where does that ĉome from?

Comment: This code has serious SQL injection problems - if it is live on the web, please consider using parameter binding instead, to reduce the likelihood of getting hacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java code is doing a Base64 encode of the image *before* sending it to the server. You do not need to encode it a second time when you go to display it. The result is a base64 encoded string of a base64 encoded string, which isn't what you want to do.

Try this instead:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $row['image'] . '"/>';
```

Comment: I understand my mistake but I tried this code and the page gives me error

Comment: What error? Is it a PHP error or does it just not display like you expect?

Comment: This web page is a default error 403 web page at Biz.nf web hosting service provider
that indicates that the access to the requested web page is strictly forbidden.

Comment: @mikotor That error has nothing to do with this. You should contact your hosting provider.

Comment: Thank you so much for your post. I've moved to Cloud9 and it worked!